# ethers js - transaction failed on swapExactETHForTokens

Tags: javascript, ethers.js

Trying to swap pairs (FTM/CRV) on fantom network via SpiritSwap router but keeps getting transaction failed error on CALL_EXCEPTION code.

I'm fairly new to blockchain, i'm guessing the payableAmount is not the right as i tried executing on ftmscan and the method takes in decimal numbers instead of bignumber. How do I do this with ethers js ?

```
import { config } from "dotenv";
config();

import { ethers } from "ethers";

const { ACCOUNT, ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
  "https://rpcapi.fantom.network"
);
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY);
const account = wallet.connect(provider);

const data = {
  ftm: "0x21be370D5312f44cB42ce377BC9b8a0cEF1A4C83",
  crv: "0x1E4F97b9f9F913c46F1632781732927B9019C68b",
  factory: "0xEF45d134b73241eDa7703fa787148D9C9F4950b0",
  router: "0xF491e7B69E4244ad4002BC14e878a34207E38c29",
  buyAmount: "0.001",
  slippage: 1,
  gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits("100", "gwei"),
  gasLimit: 200000,
};

const factory = new ethers.Contract(
  data.factory,
  [
    "function getPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external view returns (address pair)",
  ],
  account
);

const router = new ethers.Contract(
  data.router,
  [
    "function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] memory path) public view returns (uint[] memory amounts)",
    "function swapExactETHForTokens(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)",
    "function swapExactTokensForTokens(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external returns (uint[] memory amounts)",
  ],
  account
);

const run = async () => {
  console.clear();

  let pairAddress = await factory.getPair(
    ethers.utils.getAddress(data.ftm),
    ethers.utils.getAddress(data.crv)
  );

  let amountOutMin;

  const amountIn = ethers.utils.parseUnits(data.buyAmount, "ether");
  if (parseInt(data.slippage) !== 0) {
    const amounts = await router.getAmountsOut(amountIn, [data.ftm, data.crv]);
    amountOutMin = amounts[1].sub(amounts[1].div(data.slippage));
  }

  try {
    const tx = await router.swapExactETHForTokens(
      amountIn,
      amountOutMin,
      [data.ftm, data.crv],
      ACCOUNT,
      Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 5,
      {
        gasLimit: data.gasLimit,
        gasPrice: data.gasPrice,
        nonce: null,
      }
    );

    const receipt = await tx.wait();
    console.log(receipt);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

run();
```

getting error response

```
{
  reason: 'transaction failed',
  code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
  transactionHash: '0xdd7b0aa361d445a57fd55f99e458767ab1b965a7b89d1e72a2f88cb9ceb88d66',
  transaction: {
    nonce: 80,
    gasPrice: BigNumber { _hex: '0x174876e800', _isBigNumber: true },
    gasLimit: BigNumber { _hex: '0x030d40', _isBigNumber: true },
    to: '0xF491e7B69E4244ad4002BC14e878a34207E38c29',
    value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x00', _isBigNumber: true },
    data: '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',
    chainId: 250,
    v: 535,
    r: '0xa850a6c9fb8d894706e0386dd7cd1bf8f9de18495762989e0328515d38a88f0e',
    s: '0x2ef2e9eee096676903581f3fa34dcff8a816307d6104efb5422c33c9a4d6e56d',
    from: '0x7D186Aa3c3ff705fA57D452CF6E7701F2FE6457d',
    hash: '0xdd7b0aa361d445a57fd55f99e458767ab1b965a7b89d1e72a2f88cb9ceb88d66',
    type: null,
    wait: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  receipt: {
    to: '0xF491e7B69E4244ad4002BC14e878a34207E38c29',
    from: '0x7D186Aa3c3ff705fA57D452CF6E7701F2FE6457d',
    contractAddress: null,
    transactionIndex: 21,
    gasUsed: BigNumber { _hex: '0x9f9d', _isBigNumber: true },
    logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    blockHash: '0x00004b9e0000014bfd48bcf046b1dc693e82c2dfd9763342140902c2f535c7cf',
    transactionHash: '0xdd7b0aa361d445a57fd55f99e458767ab1b965a7b89d1e72a2f88cb9ceb88d66',
    logs: [],
    blockNumber: 11094328,
    confirmations: 1,
    cumulativeGasUsed: BigNumber { _hex: '0x302e6b', _isBigNumber: true },
    status: 0,
    byzantium: true
  }
}
```

Comment: There are many things that may go wrong, but at least you have forgotten to include `value` for your transaction, since you want to trade Eth into tokens. And in general, if you're a beginner, I strongly recommend you to start with something easier - these are not the easiest things to play around with

Comment: what is the failure reason with debug.traceTransaction() ? most errors in swapping are do to missing approval. debug the transactions and check what error text it is giving after hex decoding returnValue